# nginx with node.js proxy and external api call

Tags: node.js, nginx, soundcloud, restify

I am working on a project where there are two parts:

- the website (AngularJS)
- the API (node.js with Restify) listening on port 3000

On my debian server, I have configured nginx like that for the API:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
      proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:3000;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the API make some call to the SoundCloud API (api.soundcloud.com).

I think the Nginx server doesn't allow the call and we get in response "Forbidden".
The code of API is OK because in my laptop it's working.

**Do you have any idea how can I solve it?**

**EDIT:**
The javascript (ES6) code (i use node v6.5.0):

```
const SC = require('soundcloud-node-es6');

SC.init({
    id:     'ID',
    secret: 'SECRET',
});

SC.get('/tracks', {
    q: 'panda',
})
.then((tracks) => console.log(tracks))
.catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

This code only works "in local". When I run it on my server (with and without nginx), it doesn't work and send me back:

```
{ code: 403, message: 'Forbidden' }
```

Comment: What is in the Nginx error log?

Comment: Nothing. I will upload a sample of the node.js code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.
SoundCloud banned every OVH dedicated server.

From the SoundCloud staff:

> Unfortunately, our Trust & Safety engineers needed to block OVH for SoundCloud, as it was causing a lot of spam and fake activity to come through. :-/

More informations here:
https://www.soundcloudcommunity.com/soundcloud/topics/403-forbidden-when-using-ovh-vpn

Comment: Thank you for coming back and posting what you had found.